# Kindle Touch 4th Generation does not render published font correctly

Tags: kindle, calibre, fonts, font-rendering

I am using Calibre to create an ebook in Urdu language. The language is written from right to left. The whole book is in Unicode and uses UTF-8 encoding. If I open the book in TextEdit on Mac. Mac own fonts such as Helvetica shows the book like this:

[Macbook TextEdit Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqyxq.png)

When using default Kindle fonts like Caecilia this is how it looks like

[On Kindle with Default Font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gfqli.jpg)

However, when I use the published font i.e. the TTF font I have embedded in the ebook. It doesn't join the characters the way it's supposed to for languages like Arabic/Urdu. It shows each letter individually and it looks like:

[On Kindle with published font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlByZ.jpg)

Am I missing something here or Kindle just can't use these embedded fonts correctly for non-latin languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem with help from mobileread forum. I am posting the link to answer here https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showpost.php?p=3849282&postcount=2